# Create custom VisualState in xaml and manually set it in CodeBehind

Tags: wpf, xaml, coding-style

I have a TabItem style, which has VisualStates.

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"> 
<!-- Tab turns bronze when mouseover -->
</VisualState>
```

Now I want to have a custom visual state and manually set the state in codebehind instead of relying on the MouseOver event.

```
<VisualState x:Name="CustomVisualState">
<!-- this will be a storyboard to cause flashing -->
</VisualState>
```

Then I need to set it in CodeBehind.

```
MyTabItem.VisualState = CustomVisualState.  //something like this
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried
`VisualStateManager.GoToState`

Takes a Control, string with the custom state name and a bool flag for using transitions.

#### Example Usage From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991369(v=vs.110).aspx)

```cs
private void UpdateStates(bool useTransitions)
{
    if (Value >= 0)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Positive", useTransitions);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Negative", useTransitions);
    }

    if (IsFocused)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Focused", useTransitions);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Unfocused", useTransitions);
    }
}
```

---

### A slightly more complicated example usage from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313023639/http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2009/12/29/no-more-magic-strings-with-visualstatemanager-gotostate.aspx)

> Given this xaml

```xml
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="LightBlue">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SG1">
                  <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                      <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:01">
                          <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                              <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                          </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                      </VisualTransition>
                  </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                  <VisualState x:Name="SG1Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="SG1EllipseRight" >
                      <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                              <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="320"/>
                          </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" 
                   Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,98,0,0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
              <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                  <TransformGroup>
                      <ScaleTransform/>
                      <SkewTransform/>
                      <RotateTransform/>
                      <TranslateTransform/>
                  </TransformGroup>
              </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
          </Ellipse>
      </Grid>
```

> Changing state can be done like so.

```cs
 VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, SG1EllipseRight.Name, true);
```

> Or alternatively

```cs
VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "SG1EllipseRight", true);
```

Comment: Updated to include example from article (with updated link) and mdsn example

Comment: Thank you @Terrance

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(Control, "StateName", true/false);
```

or

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control, "StateName", true/false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The VisualStateManager also enables you to specify when a control
>   enters a specific state. The method that you should call to change
>   states depends on your scenario. If you create a control that uses the
>   VisualStateManager in its ControlTemplate, call the GoToState method.
>   For more information about how to create controls that use the
>   VisualStateManager, see Creating a Control That Has a Customizable
>   Appearance. If you use the VisualStateManager outside of a
>   ControlTemplate (for example, if you use a VisualStateManager in a
>   UserControl or in a single element), call the GoToElementState method.
>   In either case, the VisualStateManager performs the logic that is
>   required to appropriately start and stop the storyboards that are
>   associated with the involved state. - [VisualStateManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=netframework-4.7.2)

That is how different between **GoToElementState** and **GoToState**.