# How should I set animation run to a dependency property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a custom control inherit from textbox. When the mouse is over and not focused, then change color of the border.

Firstly, I added a dependency property to it:

```
  public Brush HoverBorderBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(HoverBorderBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HoverBorderBrushProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HoverBorderBrush.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverBorderBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HoverBorderBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(STextBox), null);
```

And here is the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:STextBox}">   
        <Setter Property="HoverBorderBrush" Value="#bfbfbf"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:STextBox}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" x:Name="B">
                          <TextBox Background="Transparent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                                  AcceptsReturn="{TemplateBinding AcceptsReturn}" AcceptsTab="{TemplateBinding AcceptsTab}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  AllowDrop="{TemplateBinding AllowDrop}" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                  Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"
                                 IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding IsHitTestVisible}" IsUndoEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsUndoEnabled}" SelectionBrush="{TemplateBinding SelectionBrush}" SelectionTextBrush="{TemplateBinding SelectionTextBrush}" x:Name="TBox"></TextBox>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                       
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=TBox}" Value="false"  />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="{Binding HoverBorderBrush,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="B">
                                            <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                            </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="{Binding BorderBrush,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="B">
                                            <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                            </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

After the code runs, it reports an error:

```
Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.
```

It seems because stroryboard can not freeze the dependency property. How can I solve this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: @Clemens Whereas, I need match multi condition. It seems VisualStateManager cannot achieve this.

Comment: You may create [custom visual states](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7839235/1136211), e.g. one called `UnfocusedMouseOver`.